# JPQL+ MYSQL to get rid of `You can't specify target table XXX for update in FROM clause`

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

There is an `AccessLog` table which logs which user (FK **user_id**) accesses which mail (FK **mail_id**) at which time(column **created**).

The table grows as time goes by. I want to keep the latest row (which user last accesses which mail) , removing all old logs.

The following SQL code works as expected:

```
delete from AccessLog where id not in (
  select id from (
    select a.id from AccessLog a
    where a.created = 
      (select max(b.created) from AccessLog b 
       where b.user_id = a.user_id 
       and   b.mail_id = a.mail_id
      )
    group by a.user_id , a.mail_id
  ) as tmpTable
)
```

The SQL is weird because of [MySQL's limitation](http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/) , and has been [discussed many times in stackoverflow.com](http://bit.ly/1UGYXzt)

Anyway , it works. But I want a version of JPA's Query Language.

I don't know how to make JPA 2 (with Hibernate implementation) generate such SQL code.

The only JPQL I can write is like this :

```
delete from AccessLog b where b not in (
  select a from AccessLog a
    where a.created = 
      (select max(b.created) from AccessLog b 
       where b.user = a.user 
       and b.mail = a.mail
      )
  group by a.user , a.mail
)
```

which generates MySQL-incompatable SQL :

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        AccessLog 
    where
        id not in  (
            select
                log1_.id 
            from
                AccessLog log1_ 
            where
                log1_.created=(
                    select
                        max(log2_.created) 
                    from
                        AccessLog log2_ 
                    where
                        log2_.user_id=log1_.user_id 
                        and log2_.mail_id=log1_.mail_id
                ) 
            group by
                log1_.user_id ,
                log1_.mail_id)
```

And causes the famous error : **MySQL can’t specify target table for update in FROM clause**

I can sure use crontable execute the working SQL code regularly . But I want a JPQL version.

I wonder how to make JPQL generate mysql-compatible SQL code as mentioned ?

Another not-so-related question is how to translate such SQL

```
select a.* from AccessLog a inner join
  (select mail_id , user_id , max(created) as maxCreated
    from AccessLog b group by mail_id , user_id
    ) b
  on  a.mail_id = b.mail_id
  and a.user_id = b.user_id
  and a.created = b.maxCreated
```

to JPQL ?

It uses inner join to select **which user last access which mail** . But It seems unable to translate to JPQL .

Environments :

```
spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.2
hibernate-jpa-2.1
MySQL 5.7.10
```

Comment: The correct solution for this (in MySQL) is to use a `JOIN`.  Does JPA support joins in `delete` statements?

Comment: Ya , I know , such as `selecting latest` is this `select a.* from AccessLog a inner join
  (select mail_id , user_id , max(created) as maxCreated
    from AccessLog b group by mail_id , user_id
    ) b
  on  a.mail_id = b.mail_id
  and a.user_id = b.user_id
  and a.created = b.maxCreated`
But It seems harder to translate to JPQL (for delete)

Comment: @Smallufo Have you tried using the CriteriaDelete<T> option in JPA 2.1?

Comment: @Naros, why would that make a difference? All that Criteria does is allow the EXACT SAME THINGS as JPQL.