# Delete from table on same select same table mariadb using jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I need delete from table on operation of same table .JPA query  is

```
DELETE  FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity a 
Where a.elLedgerid IN 
 (SELECT P.elLedgerid FROM
   (SELECT MAX(b.elLedgerid) 
    FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity b
    WHERE b.accountId='24' and b.ledgerType='Electricity Ledger' and b.postType='ARREARS') P );
```

I got this error:

> with root cause org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected
>   token: ( near line 1, column 109 [DELETE  FROM
>   com.bcits.bfm.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity a Where a.elLedgerid IN (
>   SELECT P.elLedgerid FROM ( SELECT MAX(b.elLedgerid) FROM
>   com.bcits.ElectricityLedgerEntity b WHERE b.accountId='24'
>   and b.ledgerType='Electricity Ledger' and b.postType='ARREARS') P )  ]
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)

Same query is running on mysql terminal ,but this is not working with jpa .Can any one tell me how i can write this query using jpa .

Comment: it tells you where the problem is ... column (character) 109 in that query. Compare it with the JPQL spec and you have your answer

Comment: Do you want to delete `ElectricityLedgerEntity` with max ID?

Comment: @ujulu   Yes i want to delete ElectricityLedgerEntity with  max ID .

Comment: Since you don't seem to want to look at character 109, it is your FROM clause in the SUBQUERY. You cannot have a SUBQUERY as the FROM candidate, as per the JPA spec

Comment: Convert to multi-table DELETE using JOIN, instead of IN(SELECT...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you use `P`before the last parenthesis...

The following code is not enough ?

```
DELETE  FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity a 
Where a.elLedgerid IN    
  (SELECT MAX(b.elLedgerid) 
   FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity b
   WHERE b.accountId='24' and b.ledgerType='Electricity Ledger' and
   b.postType='ARREARS')
```

**Edit for bypassing mysql subquery limitations :**

The new error `java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'LEDGER' for update in FROM clause`
is known in mysql when you use it with JPA. It's one MySQL limitation.
[A recent stackoverflow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707267/jpql-mysql-to-get-rid-of-you-cant-specify-target-table-xxx-for-update-in-from)
In brief, you cannot "directly" updated/deleted a table that you query in a `select` clause

Now I understand why your original query did multiple subqueries seemingly not necessary (while it was useful for mysql) and had a "special" syntax.
I don't know tricks to solve this problem in JPA (I don't use the MySQL DBMS for a long time now).

At your place, I would do two queries. The first  where you select the expected max elLedgerid and the second where you could delete line(s) with the id retrieved in the previous query.
You should not have performance issues if your sql model is well designed, the sql indexes well placed and the time to access to the database is correct.

Comment: this not working for me , can you me any suggest how i can do this

Comment: @ anuj dhiman
I have edited the query to have a single subquery.  According to the logs, parenthesis may be the culprit.
I don't think the subquery was needed. Can you test  and give me the error.

Comment: updated qeury show me error :         java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'LEDGER' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a single query with Hibernate.  If you want to delete the max row(s) with Hibernate you will have to do so in two steps.  First, you can find the max entry, then you can delete using that value in the `WHERE` clause.

But the query you wrote *should* actually run as a raw MySQL query.  So why don't you try executing that query as a raw query:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity a " +
             "WHERE a.elLedgerid IN (SELECT P.elLedgerid FROM " +
             "(SELECT MAX(b.elLedgerid) FROM com.model.ElectricityLedgerEntity b " + 
             "WHERE b.accountId = :account_id AND b.ledgerType = :ledger_type AND " +
             " b.postType = :post_type) P );";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("account_id", "24");
query.setParameter("ledger_type", "Electricity Ledger");
query.setParameter("post_type", "ARREARS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to extend [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538921/5070879):

> *In brief, you cannot "directly" updated/deleted a table that you query in a select clause*

This was lifted with starting from MariaDB 10.3.1:

> [**Same Source and Target Table**](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/delete/)
>
> Until MariaDB 10.3.1, deleting from a table with the same source and target was not possible. From MariaDB 10.3.1, this is now possible. For example:
>
> ```
> DELETE FROM t1 WHERE c1 IN (SELECT b.c1 FROM t1 b WHERE b.c2=0);
> ```